# Cannot resize Gedit window

Tags: debian, gedit

Gedit 3.14 in Debian 8 has no window manager decoration and the window cannot be resized. Do I need to install any additional package to make it work or has Gedit become unusable outside of the Gnome desktop? I use the window manager Blackbox.

Edit: Window resizing works in Openbox.

Screenshot:

[image: Gedit window].

Comment: I am using fluxbox and have teh same issue. it makes gedit useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Pluma* is a Gedit fork without client-side decorations, which means it includes the usual the window borders and title bar.

```
# apt-get install pluma
```

Below is a screenshot with the window manager Blackbox.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Move the mouse at the bottom edge, press [alt + middle mouse button], and then drag it.

If it is hard to press the middle button, press [alt + right mouse] to bring context menu

If your mouse does not have middle button, you can press left and right buttons together.

If you use mate, your [alt] key is the [meta] key (win key)

[image]

I have problem with pluma, btw. The plugins do not work, even I had compiled them from this source: https://github.com/yselkowitz/pluma-plugins

I do need multiedit plugin to edit column text and can't live without it!

Comment: I like this answer best because (a) it works also on Ubuntu (b) it avoids using external commands that could easily affect the wrong window and (c) it allows me to solve the problem inherent to __gedit__ while still preserving the _benefits_ of __gedit__. (I tried __pluma__ per one of the other suggestions, and it was in so many _other_ ways _inferior_ to __gedit__.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug. You can use something like this:

```
wmctrl -r gedit -e 1,0,0,558,450
```

As described [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/resize-a-window-to-a-specific-size-in-ubuntu/). `-r` is to resize a window, in this case gedit. `-e` is the way we want to resize. 1 means northwest, then we have x and y positions of the top left corner, and finally new width and height.

This will change the window size and position in fluxbox on debian at least, but the window still doesn't have a proper frame and it's not re-sizable or movable.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. However, I have switched to the Gedit fork Pluma which has the old Gedit appearance.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom That should be an answer, not a comment :-)

Comment: @Onnonymous OK, now it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible using a little trick without install other tools.
you have first to enable the embedded plug-in Python Console; you can find it in Edit --> Preference ---> Python Console (as you can see in the Picture)

[image]

then click on the bottom to the Python Console button ad you can resize your windows directly using the methods of the class window implemented in the Python Console (as you can see in the following picture):

[image]

In this example i resized the windows ( weight and height of 240px ) with the command:

```
window.resize(240,240)
```

where, from the help, the method needs two inputs:

```
resize(self, width:int, height:int)
```

There are a lot of other methods (e.g. window.fullscreen)
you can just use the command "help()" to show all methods of the class window:

```
help(window)
```